# Retaining depth information and recursive traversals

Tags: javascript, recursion, node.js, pathfinding

I have been using the pattern below for some time and it has worked well, but more than once I have almost bled my brain out of my ear trying to keep track of:

- the recursion depth
- the recursion path

I commented the line of the code where the information I would like to retain is generated:

> ```
> //if recurse
> ```

What are your suggestions on keeping track of the directory depth with out changing the structure of the code?

Also, is there a formal definition of this pattern anywhere, this sort of scan and que loop? I would very much like to study more of these.

```
module.exports = (function(FOLDER,HIDDEN){

  if(! FOLDER       ) throw new Error()
  if(! HIDDEN.slice ) throw new Error()

  var mime = require('mime')
  var Url  = require('path')
  var fs = require('fs')
  var async = require('async')


  return function(req,res,next){

      var _ROOT_  =   Url.resolve( '/' , req.params[0] || '' ) 

      var _results = []
      var _err     = []
      var _que     = [_ROOT_]

      function run(){
          if(_que.length)
            read(_que.pop(),function CB(err,results){
              if(err){
                res.json({results:null})
                return
              }

              _results = _results.concat(results)
              run()
            },_que,_err)
          else{
            res.json({results:_results})
          }
      }
        run()
  }

      function read(path,_cb,_que,_err){

        var output = []

        async.series([

        function readdir(cb){
          fs.readdir(FOLDER+'/'+path,function(err,results){
              if(err){ cb(err) ; return }
              output = results
              cb(null,null)
          })
        },
        function filterHidden (cb){
            output = output.filter(function(path){
              return ~! HIDDEN.indexOf(path)
            })
            cb(null,null)
        },
        function type  (_cb){
            async.map(output,function(file,cb){
              fs.stat(FOLDER+'/'+path+'/'+file,function(err,stats){
              var result  = (path =='/' || !path)? ['/'+file] : [ path+'/'+file]

                  if(err){  
                    _err.push(['stat',file])
                    cb(null,[])  
                    return
                  }
                  if ( stats.isDirectory()){  
                       result.push('Directory')
                       //if recurse 
                       _que.push( result[0] )
                  } else if ( stats.isFile()){
                      switch(mime.lookup(file).split('/')[0]){
                        case 'image':
                           result.push('Image')
                        break;;
                        case 'application':
                           result.push('Text')
                        break;;
                        default     :
                          _err.push('mime',file)
                          cb(null,[])
                          return
                        break;;
                      }
                  } else{
                          _err.push('dangerFile',file)
                          cb(null,[])
                          return
                  }

                    cb(null,result)
              })
            },function(err,results){
              output = results
              _cb(null,null)
            })


        },
        function filter (cb){
            output = output.filter(function(path){
              return path.length == 2
            })
            cb(null,null)
        },
        ],function(err,results){
            if(err)
                switch(err.code){
                  case 'ENOENT':
                    _cb('ENOENT',null)
                    return
                  break;;
                  case 'ENOTDIR':
                    _cb('ENOTDIR',null)
                    return
                  break;;
                  default:
                   throw new Error(err)
                  break;;
                }
            _cb(null,output)
        })

      }
})
```

If you have any other suggestions comments not directly related to the question, please offer them.

**EDIT:** The code now retains the depth information:

```
module.exports = (function(FOLDER,HIDDEN){

  if(! FOLDER       ) throw new Error()
  if(! HIDDEN.slice ) throw new Error()

  var mime  = require('mime')
  var Url   = require('path')
  var fs    = require('fs')
  var async = require('async')



      var DEPTH = 0
  function explore(req,res,next){

      var RESULTS = []
      var ERROR   = []
      var  QUE    = [ Url.resolve( '/' , req.params[0] || '' ) ]
      var _QUE    = []


      function run(){

          if(!QUE.length && _QUE.length){
              DEPTH++
              QUE = _QUE
             _QUE = []
          }


          if(QUE.length)
            read(QUE.pop(),function CB(err,results){
              if(err){
                res.json({results:null})
                return
              }

              RESULTS = RESULTS.concat(results)
              run()
            },_QUE,ERROR)
          else{
            res.json({results:RESULTS})
          }
      }
        run()
  }

      function read(path,_cb,QUE,ERROR){

        var output = []

        async.series([

        function readdir(cb){
          fs.readdir(FOLDER+'/'+path,function(err,results){
              if(err){ cb(err) ; return }
              output = results
              cb(null,null)
          })
        },
        function filterHidden (cb){
            output = output.filter(function(path){
              return ~! HIDDEN.indexOf(path)
            })
            cb(null,null)
        },
        function type  (_cb){
            async.map(output,function(file,cb){
              fs.stat(FOLDER+'/'+path+'/'+file,function(err,stats){
              var result  = (path =='/' || !path)? ['/'+file] : [ path+'/'+file]

                  if(err){  
                    ERROR.push(['stat',file])
                    cb(null,[])  
                    return
                  }
                  if ( stats.isDirectory()){  
                       result.push('Directory'+DEPTH)
                       //if recurse 
                       QUE.push( result[0] )
                  } else if ( stats.isFile()){
                      switch(mime.lookup(file).split('/')[0]){
                        case 'image':
                           result.push('Image')
                        break;;
                        case 'application':
                           result.push('Text')
                        break;;
                        default     :
                          ERROR.push('mime',file)
                          cb(null,[])
                          return
                        break;;
                      }
                  } else{
                          ERROR.push('dangerFile',file)
                          cb(null,[])
                          return
                  }

                    cb(null,result)
              })
            },function(err,results){
              output = results
              _cb(null,null)
            })


        },
        function filter (cb){
            output = output.filter(function(path){
              return path.length == 2
            })
            cb(null,null)
        },
        ],function(err,results){
            if(err)
                switch(err.code){
                  case 'ENOENT':
                    _cb('ENOENT',null)
                    return
                  break;;
                  case 'ENOTDIR':
                    _cb('ENOTDIR',null)
                    return
                  break;;
                  default:
                   throw new Error(err)
                  break;;
                }
            _cb(null,output)
        })

      }


  explore.cmd = function _explore(path,cb){
    debugger
    explore({params:[path]},{
    json:function(response){
      cb(response.err,response.results)
    }})
  }

  return explore
})
```

Comment: This 'scan and queue' concept is used by a breadth-first-search, and it closely resembles what you are doing here. Hmmm ... a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRq6p9s8NVg) and [a Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth_first_search)

Answer (score 4):

This review is only going to focus on style, since one of your specific questions has been answered and the other one you've already worked out (for what it's worth I'm not entirely sure those questions were on-topic here to begin with, but there's plenty to review anyway).

---

Your code:

```
module.exports = (function(FOLDER,HIDDEN){
```

- There is no need to enclose this function in parentheses. Since it is the rvalue of an assignment operation, it will be parsed as a function expression.
- Only identifiers representing constants should be in ALL_CAPS. Arguments can never be constants; they should use camelCase.
- The "folder" concept is a metaphor used by GUIs like desktop environments. In a situation like this, the name "directory" would probably be more appropriate, but still isn't very specific. Consider "basePath" or similar.
- The name "hidden" does not give us any clue as to what type of value it expects. Since it expects an array of paths, something like "hiddenPaths" might be better.
- Leaving a space between each parameter and after the parameter list is generally considered to be good style.

Revised code:

```
module.exports = function(basePath, hiddenPaths) {
```

---

Your code:

```
if(! FOLDER       ) throw new Error()
if(! HIDDEN.slice ) throw new Error()
```

- Unlike functions, keywords like `if`, `switch`, and so on should have a space before the parenthetical expression(s) that follows. Keywords like `else` should have a space before the following brace.
- The whitespace inside the parenthetical is awkward.
- Although it's becoming more popular in some circles, relying on automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) is still not going to fly in most team environments.
- Omitting braces, with the exception of `else if`, is often frowned upon in team environments.
- The errors you throw should contain messages that give some indication of what went wrong.
- You attempt to check whether HIDDEN is an array by testing for a `slice` property, but strings also have a `slice` property. It would make more sense to check the property you actually use, `indexOf`, except strings have an `indexOf` property as well. Use `instanceof Array` or check for a property like `push` instead.
- Consider making the second argument optional; it seems likely that someone might want to use this without hiding any paths, and passing an empty array is a bit awkward.

Revised code:

```
if (!hiddenPaths) {
    hiddenPaths = [];
}
if (!basePath) {
    throw new Error("basePath is required");
}
if (!hiddenPaths.push) {
    throw new Error("hiddenPaths must be an array");
}
```

---

Your code:

```
var Url   = require('path')
```

- Only constructor functions meant to be invoked with `new` should be named with initial caps.
- The extra whitespace is awkward.

Revised code:

```
var url = require('path');
```

---

Your code:

```
  var RESULTS = []
  var ERROR   = []
  var  QUE    = [ Url.resolve( '/' , req.params[0] || '' ) ]
  var _QUE    = []
```

- These are not constants, so they shouldn't be written in all caps.
- Since "error" is an array, "errors" would be a more appropriate name.
- *Que* is not an English word; you want *queue*.
- What distinguishes the second queue variable from the first one? Give them meaningful, distinct names. Also, only properties of objects meant to be considered "private" should be prefixed with an underscore.
- Awkward whitespace and ASI.

Revised code:

```
  var results = [];
  var errors = [];
  var queue = [url.resolve('/', req.params[0] || '')];
  var nextQueue = [];
```

---

There are more examples of the same kind of stylistic issues throughout the code; you should be able to spot them now.

Some other notes:

- Your indentation is inconsistent. In some places you use 2 spaces, in some places you use 4, in other places you use 7. Pick something and stick with it.
- The double semicolon after `break` serves no purpose; it is inconsistent with your style of relying on ASI and is also inconsistent with the more common style of using a (single) semicolon to terminate each statement.
- There is a lot of extra vertical space. One common convention is to leave a blank line after variable declarations, a blank line before `return` statements, and a blank line between functions, with no other blank lines. In some places you have two or three blank lines in a row; you might want to tighten this up.
- Your use of [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) throughout the code is unusual, and could be confusing to someone reading the code. When you see a named function you generally expect it to be called (by name) from somewhere else, but that's not the case here. You may want to do this anyway to get more readable stack traces, but make sure you really think that outweighs the value of having more readable and less confusing code.

Comment: Changing from folder to directory is an especially good idea . The named function is actually exactly that a label for a stack trace . Im at a toss about using the all caps I can see it giving people heart attacks but I have been toying with the idea of using it to VISUALLY STAND OUT and keep track of the closure level. _X - one level deep __X to levels deep etc... the indentation style is scary but serves as visual reminders to me of whats happening in the code but your review shows people don`t see that and should be changed on release to help communities read my code .